# Find the sum of series $ (a+b)+(a^2+b^2+ab)+(a^3+b^3+ab^2+a^2b)+.... $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$ (a+b)+(a^2+b^2+ab)+(a^3+b^3+ab^2+a^2b)+.... $$
Find sum upto the n term. Will I have to find the nth term and do its summation? Or there is any other method to do it?

In the book this answer is given:$\frac{(a^2(1-a^n))}{((a-b)(1-a))}+\frac{(b^2(1-b^n)}{((a-b)(1-b))} $

Comment: The given formula looks wrong to me. It should be symmetric in $a,b$ at least.

Comment: Your formula looks correct.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah thanks I have corrected it.

Comment: It is still not symmetric.

Comment: No this answer is only given in the book.

Comment: It must be wrong, then. If $\phi(a,b)$ is a formula, then $\phi(b,a)$  must produce the same formula (since the original sum is symmetric in $a,b$), however the above formula has $\phi(b,a) = -\phi(a,b)$.

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake with $ (a+b)^2 $ this is the original question. how to solve this.?

Comment: @Neer you have not given us enough information about $a$ or $b$, Also, the only thing you've done is an expansion on each term. Are there infinitely many terms now? I'm confused....

Comment: No n terms are there. a and b are constants and the power of a and b increases upto n.

Comment: @Neer indeed things are changed now. Deleting my answer.

Comment: Or you can edit it if you have got the answer of this.Thank you for your help @RustynYazdanpour

Comment: @Neer no problem

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480115/sequences-series-the-sum-to-n-terms-of-a-progression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(a+b)+(a^2+b^2+ab)+(a^3+b^3+a^2b+ab^2)+\dots$$Recognize our general terms appear to be of the form $\dfrac{a^k-b^k}{a-b}$ for $k\ge2$. This lets us rewrite our series as such:$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{a^k-b^k}{a-b}=\frac1{a-b}\sum_{k=2}^n(a^k-b^k)=\frac1{a-b}\left(\sum_{k=2}^na^k-\sum_{k=2}^nb^k\right)$$We know that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^nr^k=\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ hence we have:$$\sum_{k=2}^na^k=a^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}a^k=a^2\frac{1-a^{n-1}}{1-a}\\\sum_{k=2}^nb^k=b^2\frac{1-b^{n-1}}{1-b}$$This ultimately yields the result$$\frac1{a-b}\left(a^2\frac{1-a^{n-1}}{1-a}-b^2\frac{1-b^{n-1}}{1-b}\right)=\frac{a^2(1-a^{n-1})}{(a-b)(1-a)}-\frac{b^2(1-b^{n-1})}{(a-b)(1-b)}$$The difference between mine and your final expressions is that yours is valid for the sum up to the term $\dfrac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$ while mine sums only up to $\dfrac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$.

Comment: Thank you! How did you get the general formula?

Comment: It is common -- I recognized it. You can also consider it is a symmetric polynomial and consider what happens when you multiply throughout by $a-b$... especially of $a-b$ appear like that in the denominator.

Comment: Thank you ! And I guess the summation should start from $ k=1 $

Comment: No, the summation starts at $k=2$ @Neer. $$\frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}=a+b$$